# Target HTML generated by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider button created using a JavaScript plugin, which automatically generates an element with class name `.flex-next`. However, when I run the following code, nothing is logged in my console:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $( ".flex-next" ).on( "click", function() {
        console.log("youclick");
    })
});
```

Comment: Read about "event delegation" in JavaScript.

Comment: see this: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting your call to fire when the window loads by using `$(window).load(...);`. A flexsider is initiated on `$(document).ready(...)` which happens after the window loads and all of the content is loaded into the DOM. So when your script fires, it looks for an element that isnt there yet.

Get around this by firing your script on $(document).ready(), and use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). The best practice way is to declare your function like so:

```
$(document).ready(
    $(document).on('click', ".flex-next", function() {
        console.log("youclick");
    });
});
```

this way your click listener will wait until the page is ready and will put a click event on to any `.flex-next` event, even those created dynamically. That way if your using large imagery that is loaded asynchronously the code will still work.

Answer (score 2):

Since the button is added dynamically after the dom is loaded, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so the click event can be used on this button:

```
$(document).on('click','.flex-nex',function() {
    console.log("youclick");
})
```

Comment: +1, and here is some [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to go along with it. See also, [jQuery delegate documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably calling your $(".flex-next").on call before the slider button has been executed.  So, basically, your .flex-next class doesn't exist in the DOM yet when you call the .on

You should call the .on call after plugin has been initialized.